# jQuery addClass not working on dynamic changed input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have an issue on our checkout, where we are using jQuery to add a class to the input fields, when they aren't empty.
The code has worked perfectly for our needs so far. The issue now is, that we are using a small plugin that automatic provides the city name, when the zip code is entered. When this happens, the code does not work and the class is not added to the field, until it is clicked.

I can't seem to find a proper solution for this, so any help is appreciated.

```
$('.input-text').each(function(){
    changeState($(this));
});
$('.input-text').on('focusout', function(){
    changeState($(this));
});
function changeState($formControl){
        if($formControl.val().length > 0){
        $formControl.addClass('has-value');
    }
    else{
        $formControl.removeClass('has-value');
    }
}
```

Edit - plugin code:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
        $( '#billing_postcode, #shipping_postcode' ).on( 'keyup', function () {
            var $input = $( this );
            var value = $input.val().trim();
            if ( value.length === 4 ) {
                var form_type = $input.attr( 'name' ).split( '_' )[0];
                update_city_by_postcode( value, form_type );
            }
        });
    } );
```

Comment: Does this plugin have an event that you can respond to?  Currently you're updating on the `focusout` event.  You can also update on any event exposed by the plugin, or even just try the `change` event that may be triggered by the plugin.

Comment: Note you can use `$formControl.toggleClass('has-value', $formControl.val().length > 0)`

Comment: I have shared the plugin code. I have tried the change event, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MathiasBeck: Is `update_city_by_postcode` synchronous?  Can't you just call `changeState` after that?

Comment: I have tried, but can't get it to work. Can you give me an example? I am not the best at code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is modifying the values of your inputs:

```
update_city_by_postcode( value, form_type );
```

Then you can just re-run your existing logic afterward:

```
update_city_by_postcode( value, form_type );
$('.input-text').each(function(){
    changeState($(this));
});
```